# whenever startx is typed in, I get this image

Tags: gui, noobs

With a newly set up noobs SD card. This. Screen occurs. I am a noob of r pi so simple answers may help. I can. Access python via the command line interface. But it hangs and produces this.

Note: whilst clearing my SD card there was an error. But it said it had completed it. And it isn't plugged into the internet
[image: Image after typing startx into the command line interface. Also when the open in GUI option is chosen]

Comment: `sudo less /var/log/Xorg.0.log` should give you more details about the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

A brand new installation shouldn't cause this error. Are you sure you haven't modified anything? If not, then try installing NOOBS on a different SD card and let us know what happens.